# information_schema tables and update_time behaviour

Tags: mysql, updates, information-schema

I'd like to have some explanation about information_schema and its behaviours.
Let's say I want to know when a myisam table has been modified.
I write this query

```
select update_time from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'my_db' and table_name = 'my_table'
```

Even though I apply some change to my table nothing happens in it until I run a `flush tables`.
Unluckily it seems to me that `update_time` stores date and time of the moment that I run flush tables, not the one when table changes really occur. Is it true?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just curious, what kind of logic you want to make relied on that last update date?

Comment: I just want to know what kind of logic information_schema follows and if it's as it seems to be what's the utility of this metadata :) I thought that update_time meant when a table has been subject to some changes, not when I flush it. Sorry for my english :) I hope you've understood.

Comment: There is something in the manual - 'For MyISAM, the data file timestamp is used; however, on Windows the timestamp is not updated by updates so the value is inaccurate.' - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-table-status.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally prefer to add a last_change timestamp to each of my tables, then define it as "DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", which means that mysql will automatically update it each time the row is modified.

With this, you could just query the table directly and know not only that the table was touched, but also which rows were touched.

It doesn't work to detect deleted rows though.